# Input field can't display space only at the start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input field from ant-d library, which I am using to take input from user, now when the user starts typing anything other than space, it works fine. Also space in between words or after some chars works fine, just it didn't go as expected when I start typing space in the beginning( a dumb behaviour :p ). Basically I can type any char apart from space as first but space is not accounted in input field as first char.

```
<Input
        autoFocus
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="type here"
        showMaxLength
        maxLength={50}
      />
```

Comment: Are you sure it's antd? there are no such properties `maxLength` `showMaxLength` `autoFocus` in `Input`, try making a sandbox https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Actually i am using customised ant-d library where I am adding this additional props to ant-d Input field

Comment: It's important information, seems you have broken something because the default behavior is as expected, you need to create some reproducible example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes I got the problem, We were trimming the input in the customised version resulting in above scenario. Thanks a-lot, will keep above mentioned info in mind from next time :D